# Where should the security headers be? Response headers or Request headers?

Tags: security, http-headers, content-security-policy, request-headers, response-headers

The security headers like

```
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-ua-compatible:IE=edge, chrome=1
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

should be request or response headers? And why?

Answer (score 2):

All of those headers (like most http security headers) are used by the browser to enable security features in the browser.

Therefore they need to be in the response headers sent by the server to the browser.

It would do nothing to set them in the request header (sent from browser to server) as they are not used by the server.

Answer (score 0):

it should be response header , for example : x-content-type-options:nosniff: This is a security feature that helps prevent attacks based on MIME-type confusion. you can read complete details on [Veracode Site](https://www.veracode.com/blog/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers), [Owasp Site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers) , 
[MSDN Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622941(v=vs.85).aspx)